# Spectrum of a self-adjoint compact operator

Tags: hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, spectral-theory

Given a self-adjoint compact operator $A$ on a (separable) Hilbert space, is it true that the spectrum of $A$ is equal to the closure of the set of eigenvalues of $A$, or in symbols
$$
\sigma(A) = \sigma_P(A)?
$$

Comment: I've seen something like that once. In fact you should have more: either $\sigma(A)$ is exactly the set of eigenvalues. Or it is the set of eigenvalues and $0$ (and the latter is only possible if there's a sequence of eigenvalues $\lambda_n\rightarrow 0$).

Comment: I'm not completely sure about the above actually. I was talking about Theorem 3.11 in here https://www.iith.ac.in/~rameshg/NITKworkshop.pdf Do you think it implies what I said?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. For a compact operator, any nonzero eigenvalue is an isolated point (because it has to have finite multiplicity). So the only point in the spectrum that may not be an eigenvalue is zero.

Now, a selfadjoint operator has no residual spectrum, so all points in the spectrum are either eigenvalues or approximate eigenvalues. So if $0$ is not an eigenvalue, it is an approximate eigenvalue; this means that $0=\lim\lambda_j$ for some $\lambda_j$, which being nonzero will necessarily be eigenvalues. So yes, $\sigma(A)=\overline{\sigma_P(A)}$; even more concretely, 
$$
\sigma(A)=\{0\}\cup\sigma_p(A).
$$
No closure needed.

Comment: I'm coming in 2 years late. How far can you extend this? Can you remove compactness of the operator? Or the separability of $H$?

Comment: No. Even with $H$ separable there exist sefadjoint operators with no eigenvalues.